# Custom service provider for Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm new to Lumen, and have a fresh install (v8.2.4) and have followed the docs, trying to write my own service, but I keep getting error

```
 "Target class [App\Prodivers\BatmanServiceProvider] does not exist."
```

Like I said, its a fresh install according to the Lumen docs.

in /bootstrap/app.php

```
$app->register(App\Providers\BatmanServiceProvider::class);
```

in /app/Providers/BatmanServiceProvider.php

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class BatmanServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function register()
    {
        return "batman!";
    }
}
```

My controller: app/Http/Controllers/MainController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Prodivers\BatmanServiceProvider;

class MainController extends Controller{


    public function __construct(BatmanServiceProvider $BatmanServiceProvider){

    }

    public function main(){
        print "hello space!";
    }


}
```

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: ... `Prodivers` ? any reason your Controller is dependent upon an instance of the Service Provider?

Comment: Im just trying to make a service/utility/helper with some function I can reuse in multiple controllers. how would it be done? The above code is what the docs and a bunch of googling has given me.

Comment: You may have less trouble if you use full laravel.  Will simplify your life and your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. in /bootstrap/app.php

```
    $app->register(App\Providers\BatmanServiceProvider::class);
```

2. in /app/Providers/BatmanServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Services\BatmanService;

class BatmanServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(BatmanService::class, function(){
            return new BatmanService;
        });
    }
}
```

3. create Services folder in your_lumen_project/app, and create php file BatmanService.php

in /app/Services/BatmanService.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

class BatmanService
{
    public function sayHello(){
        return 'hi, space!';
    }
}
```

4. Now, you can use anywhere!

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Services\BatmanService;

class MainController extends Controller{

    protected $batmanService;
    public function __construct(BatmanService $batmanService){
        $this->batmanService = $batmanService;
    }

    public function main(){
        return $this->batmanService->sayHello(); // "hi, space!"
    }


}
```

Comment: switched from lumen to flight, but setting this as correct answer :)